# Matlab horizontal line plot with arrow

Tags: matlab, plot, horizontal-line

I am trying to plot a graph with horizontal lines with arrows on the end of the line to show continuity in Matlab. How is this possible?

Picture for reference: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYCh3.jpg]

Comment: [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html)

Comment: Maybe you can use [`quiver`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) for this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p1 = [2 3];                         % First Point
p2 = [9 3];                         % Second Point
dp = p2-p1;                         % Difference
figure(1)
quiver(p1(1),p1(2),dp(1),dp(2),0)
grid
axis([0  10    0  10])
text(p1(1),p1(2), sprintf('(%.0f,%.0f)',p1))
text(p2(1),p2(2), sprintf('(%.0f,%.0f)',p2))
```

You can even remove the grid commando and text commando to get a white background for your figure :

```
p1 = [2 3];                         % First Point
p2 = [9 3];                         % Second Point
dp = p2-p1;                         % Difference
figure(1)
quiver(p1(1),p1(2),dp(1),dp(2))
axis([0  10    0  10])
```